# Can we represent circuit with only text?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

We normally use circuit diagram to represent circuits. Is there any markdown language for circuits, so that we do not have to use images to represent a circuit.

Comment: The closest thing to a common language might be spice. The online Falstead circuit simulator also has a netlist language used when it exports circuits in text form.

Comment: [Netlist.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlist)

Comment: Also, CircuiTikZ.

Comment: A picture ( circuit diagram ) is worth a thousand words...

Answer (score 4):

### We call this a "netlist", but generally don't edit it directly as text

It is possible to represent a circuit as a serialized text representation, versus the graphical schematics we normally use.  The traditional name for this is a "netlist", as it is a *list* of components and the *nets* (nodes) that connect them together.

While there are a wide variety of formats for netlists as *schematic capture* tools generally save and load netlists instead of graphical images for compactness and portability reasons, the most commonly encountered netlist format is the one originally developed as part of Berkeley SPICE and extended several times as SPICE-based simulators became widely used.  An example of a trivial SPICE netlist (although I have not actually simulated it) for a loaded voltage divider can be found below.

```
Loaded Voltage Divider Example
* Note that Node 0 is *always* ground in SPICE
Vsrc V+ 0 DC 12
R1 V+ Vout 20K
R2 Vout 0 10K
Rload Vout 0 51K
.end
```

Comment: I am in a dilemma on which answer to accept as both seems to be correct. So, I choose to upvote both answers instead.

Answer (score 2):

LTSPICE schematics save as SPICE netlsts which are text

annother other way to do circuits in text is ASCII art eg:

```
to get 50% duty cycle the easiest way is the 1 resistor circuit,

                             ----+---  vcc
                                 |  
                   +-[R1]--------|--------+                               
                   |             |        |                               
                   |    +--------+        |                                    
                   |    |        |        |                               
                   |    | . . . .|. . . . |                               
                   |    | .   VCC(8)    . |                              
                   |    | .             . |                              
                   |    +--RES(4) OUT(3)--+--> out1 (totem pole)           
                   |      .    555      .                                
                   +-------TH(6)  DIS(7)-----> out2 (open collector)      
                   |      .             .                                
                   +-------TR(2)   CV(5)--                               
                C1 |      .             .                                
                 =====    .   GND(1)    .                                
                   |      . . . .|. . . .                               
                   |             |                                       
                   +-------------+
                                 |                                       
                              ---+-- gnd                                      

        the frequency is approximately 0.72/R1*C1
        so try R=68K and C=10nF a 10K trimmer in
        series with the resistor will help ypu get
        closer to 1Khz.
```

Comment: I am in a dilemma on which answer to accept as both seems to be correct. So, I choose to upvote both answers instead.